# gcp dag extract year month date and hour from execution time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

After executing my dag from airflow which is in python, I am getting execution time stamp as `2020-11-09T10:01:00+00:00` from `{{ts}}`

Is there a way to extract year, month, date and hour from above date.
I tried with `datetime.fromisoformat()`, but it is raising parse error while submitting dag.

Comment: Could you elaborate more what you are doing and trying to do? Where do you get this timestamp from? Where do you want to use ?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I m getting this timestamp from {{ts}} i.e execution time of dag, i want to form some directory structure based on execution time.

Comment: Do you want to use the formatted execution time in your Dag?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes yes, i want year, month, date and hour extracted from that execution time

Answer (score 1):

This block of code should work. you can replace below date in code with {{ts}}

```
from datetime import datetime 
my_date = datetime.strptime('2020-11-09T10:01:00+00:00', "%Y-%m- 
%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(my_date)
print('Month: ', my_date.month)
print('Year: ', my_date.year)
print('Day: ', my_date.day)
print('Hour: ', my_date.hour)
```